# How to set a dynamic redirect URL in Azure AD for non-static URLs

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have connected my application to Azure AD for email sending on behalf of users, as described in this previous question. However, the URLs for my application are dynamic and cannot be controlled by me. How can I set a dynamic redirect URL in Azure AD to support all these URLs?
Additionally, I am using a popup to connect my users, and I cannot access a popup that is not in the same URL, so I cannot take the code from static URL response.

My application URLs are dynamic and can take many forms, such as example1.domain.com/path/to/resource or example2.domain.com/path/to/resource. This makes it difficult to set a static redirect URL in Azure AD that will work for all possible URLs.

I have read about state parameter but i think that's not helping in my case of: *****.domain.com/path/to/resource.

I'm considering creating another app that sends its URL to my server, but I'm not sure if this is a proper solution. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

To **set a dynamic redirect URL in Azure AD**, try using the below CLI command:

```
az login

az ad app update --id ApplicationID --add replyUrls "https://*.ms"
```

[image]

For sample, I used non-static **`https://*.ms`** redirect URI.

***In the portal, redirect URI updated successfully as below:***

[image]

Now, I **authorized** the request by using the below endpoint:

> I tried to authorize the request to **`https://jwt.ms`**.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

The user signed-in successfully and redirected request to the **`https://jwt.ms`** URL as below:

[image]

When I tried to redirect the users to **`https://jwt.io`**, I got the error like below:

[image]

In your case, update the redirect URI as **`https://*****.domain.com/path/to/resource`** and try.

Comment: I must buy Azure subscription for cli use??