# How to configure Azure AD authentication for an on-premise web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

i need help to configure the Azure AD authentication for an existing on-premise web application (ASP.NET MVC).
Each client has its own installation (own database and own server).

What we want to do:

- give the possibility to use the Microsoft account to login to application (many clients manage company accounts with Microsoft Azure AD)
- minimize customer configuration

Our idea is to proceed in this way:

1. register a multi-tenant application in **our** Azure AD enabled to support all account types (organizations and privates)
2. use these parameters to connect the web app:

   - client ID: id of the application in our Azure AD
   - instance: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
   - tenant ID: common

Expected result:

- clients can login with their own Microsoft account: the AAD application support all account types
- after credentials validation, Azure creates a service principal to the client Azure with all the rules neeeded to read the user info
- no security problems: the AAD application is in our Azure but the security principal lives in the client Azure (each on-premise web app installation creates a security principal, if used)

Questions:

- Is the right way to proceed?
- How can we configure the redirect url parameter? We need to redirect the user to the home page of the web app but the url is different for each installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. To **support all Account types, create an Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** like below:

[image]

**To read the user information**, grant the API permission:

[image]

> How can we configure the redirect url parameter? We need to redirect the user to the home page of the web app but the url is different for each installation.

You can set **Dynamic redirect URL** in Azure AD but it doesn't support the Application registered as *Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts*. Refer [**Microsoft Q&A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/652275/azure-ad-or-azure-ad-b2c-redirection-url-for-multi) by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT and this [**MSDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#query-parameter-support-in-redirect-uris).

Hence, you can add **multiple static redirect URIs** in the Authentication tab like below:

[image]

**To authenticate the users**, you can make use of below authorize endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms 
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

Once, the other tenant user consents, the **auth-code** will be generated like below:

[image]

Now, this **`MultiTenantApp`** will be registered as Service Principal in the user's tenant:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the above access token, one can able to **fetch the signed in user details**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

Comment: About redirect URL: i cannot register all the customers urls (there are hundreds installations and we cannot follow all the updates or new installations). I tried to create an application only for organizations but i cannot configure a dynamic url (wilcard charaters are not allowed with applications of all types, different from the documentation...you can try). Any ideas?

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509189/how-to-set-a-dynamic-redirect-url-in-azure-ad-for-non-static-urls for setting dynamic URL for supported tenants.

Comment: So the only way is to force the url using CLI?

Comment: Yes you have to make use of CLI for dynamic URLs.

Comment: You can update the dynamic redirect url in the Azure Ad app manifest too

Comment: Doesn't work. When you save an error message appears "Error detail: Invalid value specified for property 'replyUrlsWithType'".

Comment: What is the URL you are updating?

Comment: I changed the application type (organization tenants only) and now works. But it's a work around, i don't like it. I think it's better to open a new thread about this problem. Thanks for your help.